# How can I check if the $_SESSION is locked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I've written a CMS with multiple AJAX POST calls to get data.

One of which checks if the user is logged in every x seconds by checking if

```
isset($_SESSION['key'])
```

Which works great, but if the $_SESSION is locked, i.e it's in use with another file for an extended period like uploading an image, it will ask the user to log in even if the session is valid (as the AJAX can't access it while in use).

I tried using:

```
 session_write_close();
```

on the file upload page to try and release it, but it doesn't seem to help.

The "check login" AJAX doesn't even write to the session, but it can't even seem to read it or just check if a variable isset().

Is there a way for my php script to differentiate between a locked session and a non-existant one maybe? 
Or any other ideas would be ace, thanks! :)

Comment: why would you check of a user is logged in every X seconds and not simply on page load?

Comment: @Dagon: A period of inactivity could let the session expire while the page is still open; then, when the user comes back, they may try to, say, enter some data, and will be rebuffed when the server response comes back saying they have been logged out. It is better UX to tell them they will need to log back in when it happens, rather than once they try to perform an action (and potentially lose the data associated with that action, depending on whether logging in requires redirecting to a separate page).

Comment: i understand when my bank does it, but for a cms it s pointless and im gad most don't.

Comment: Wouldn't the very action of checking if they are logged in keep them logged in though? This defeats the purpose of having an open page and logging them out ( short of laptop sleep or something ).

Comment: @Brad: If so, that may be an advantage. Session expiry may exist for several reasons, but if the primary reason is to prevent accumulation of sessions browsers no longer retain and is not in place for security reasons, it may be desirable to keep the session live as long as the browser is open.

Comment: Well, I don't know why you're worried about that. Bots will create a session per page view without fail, my code just tells the session not to init if it finds bot headers. If you have the traffic to worry about sessions you'd not be doing it this way.

Comment: Yeah as @Dagon explains, it's mostly so that users don't lose data when spending long periods over 24 minutes writing a blog for example (plus I just wanted to learn how to do it via AJAX).

Comment: If you're looking to keep a session open either extend your sessions or ping an endpoint. You need do zero logic. By pinging an endpoint, assuming your framework opens sessions every time, you've now refreshed your sessions. setInterval(function(){ doPing(); }, 30000);

Comment: Yeah the session refreshes every page load, so I guess I could just load the login to refresh the session every 20 mins or something.